# Research and Folleys/Three RO Filesystems and No Way to Get the SD Card Back Operating

Tags: linux, dd, readonly

I have this SD Card that has three read-only filesystems on it. I am using a Linux computer to try to erase via dd or another command tool.

I am currently trying to write an image to the SD Card. Nothing I found so far states that a locked SD Card because of it being read-only should stop me from proceeding with an image build.

But...it does and I cannot configure via commands what steps I should take.

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Read-only file system
```

That is one error. I have tried it with `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdb1`, and `/dev/sdb2` so far without any luck.

I tried to use `dd` to create an `if=/dev/zero` to the output file at /dev/sdb but notta so far. Just errors.

I guess using a compiled image from beagleboard.org was a choice that I needed to begin with then at that time.

I was able to use Linux to adjust the micro SD Card image and boot to fruition.

Comment: I have figured out some of the issues...The sd card was written as a /dev/sdb device while the current state of the "new" machine is using it like a /dev/mmcblk device (I thinnk) if that makes any sense. So, I have to use an outside device to write to the sd card.

Comment: Have you checked `dmesg` for errors?

Comment: yes...it seems my mmc0 is faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the Yocto build I ported to the hardware, the board was rendered useless because of the type of .dtb and booting mechanisms. The Yocto build was for an evm from TI while the hardware just had a TI chip on it, i.e. the same as the evm.

For future reference, the TDA4VM is not the same as the evm from TI. The evm from TI.com has the TDA4VM processor on it with the coprocessors like the evm but because my target board from beagleboard.org is an entirely different board, my set up was faulty...

Luckily, the people at their organization helped me a bit with building a new image that is for the BBAI-64 which has the TDA4VM. Yocto builds from what I can decipher all are related to the TI.com evm which has the TDA4VM SoC on it.